# Calling objects method and return same object using functional api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

At the moment I have:

```
cardLabels = cards.stream()
            .map(ImageSupplier::getCard)
            .map(JLabel::new)
            .collect(toList());

cardLabels.stream().forEach(container::add);
```

I can write lambda expression:

```
.map(c ->{ 
  JLabel label = new JLabel(c);
  container.add(label);
  return label;
 })
```

but it seems long. Is there something that I can call like `.doStuff(container::add)` with would return stream of `JLabel`?

Comment: Would `.map(c -> (JLabel)container.add(new JLabel(c)))` be too bad?

Comment: Method reference call would be nicer. I was just wondering if there is such a thing.

Comment: I guess you can create your own method for that, but probably will not be much nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`peek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
return cards.stream()
            .map(ImageSupplier::getCard)
            .map(JLabel::new)
            .peek(container::add);
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid mutating external data structures from inside a stream.  If `container` is not synchronized or concurrent and the stream were to be made parallel, results will be unpredictable.

Instead of trying to cram more into the stream expression, just simplify the second statement:

```
cardLabels = cards.stream()
        .map(ImageSupplier::getCard)
        .map(JLabel::new)
        .collect(toList());

container.addAll(cardLabels);
```

This way your logic cannot be accidentally screwed up by changing `stream()` to `parallelStream()`.

Comment: Yeah but, if it's just a regular stream then the behavior is perfectly predictable: *"Certain stream sources (such as List or arrays) are intrinsically ordered"* ([java.util.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description)). Making the stream parallel by accident would cause problems regardless because then the JLabels might get added to the container in the wrong order.

Comment: Being ordered doesn't make it sequential.  It just means that if you collect the stream's output into an ordered collector, the final result will be in the same order as the original. Writing into an unsynchronized collection from inside a parallel stream will leave the target collection in an unpredictable (possibly corrupted) state.

Comment: `peek` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)  says it better than I could:  "For parallel stream pipelines, the action may be called at whatever time and in whatever thread the element is made available by the upstream operation. If the action modifies shared state, it is responsible for providing the required synchronization."

Comment: *"If a stream is ordered, most operations are constrained to operate on the elements in their encounter order; if the source of a stream is a List containing [1, 2, 3], then the result of executing map(x -> x*2) must be [2, 4, 6]. [...] If a stream is ordered, repeated execution of identical stream pipelines on an identical source will produce an identical result;"* I've linked you the documentation so you could read it.

Comment: The *result* will be arranged in the same order as the source.  The actual computation may be performed in any order and in any thread.  It's easy to observe:  `Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).parallel().peek(System.out::println).collect(toList())`  See the section on [Statelessness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) and the one right after on Side-Effects

Comment: :( That's a parallel stream. I'm not talking about parallel streams. I'm talking about sequential streams, which, if they are also ordered, are deterministic.

Comment: Look at the example of things not to do in the Side-effects section.  It's pretty much the OP's question.  If you can write your stream in 2 ways - one that will break if parallelized and one that will not break, it is better to choose the latter.

Comment: The bigger problem with `peek` is that it’s execution relies on the actual terminal operation. If there is a way to complete the terminal operation operation without processing all elements, `peek` might not see all values. `peek` is more a debugging tool aiding to monitor which element were actually processed. Building the actual operation on it is discouraged.